# PDF python plot is blurry - image interpolation?

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, latex, interpolation

I want to include a python-generated pdf plot into an *Overleaf* Latex document. However the image appears blurry. A minimal example is below. I generate two plots with imshow, one with `interpolation='none'`, one with `interpolation='nearest'`. Used versions are *Python 2.7.15* and *matplotlib 2.2.3.*

Using the pdf-viewer *evince 3.20.2*, *imshow_none.pdf* has perfectly sharp pixels, while imshow_nearest.pdf shows blurry pixel edges and also pixel sizes may be different. Within the Overleaf-built-in pdf viewer under *Firefox 52.5.0*, everything is vice versa, with the blurrying being worse. When downloading the compiled pdf from Overleaf, the situation is as when viewing the files under evince. Png screenshots and the overleaf latex file are found below.

I am not an expert on interpolation. Do the pdf viewers use the matplotlib interpolation parameters or their own interpolation method? How comes once the blurry image is *imshow_none.pdf*, once *imshow_nearest.pdf*? Is the interpolation method somehow stored in the pdf? In the tags? How to read out this information? Any way to create a file that is sharp both under evince and Overleaf?

[image: Evince: imshow, interpolation='none']
[image: Evince: imshow, interpolation='nearest']
[image: Overleaf: imshow, interpolation='nearest']
[image: Overleaf: imshow, interpolation='none']

**Python code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print sys.version
print matplotlib.__version__

np.random.seed(100)
a = np.random.rand(100,50)

plt.imshow(a, cmap='binary', aspect='auto', interpolation='none', origin='lower')
plt.title('imshow, interpolation: none')
plt.savefig('/home/proxauf/test_pdf_plot_interpolation/imshow_none.pdf')
plt.close()

plt.imshow(a, cmap='binary', aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest', origin='lower')
plt.title('imshow, interpolation: nearest')
plt.savefig('/home/proxauf/test_pdf_plot_interpolation/imshow_nearest.pdf')
plt.close()
```

**Latex code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics{imshow_none.pdf}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics{imshow_nearest.pdf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Relevant: [issues/12065](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12065).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's very useful :)

Comment: Is there any way to tell whichever pdf reader to force 'nearest' interpolation? Because the python generated 'nearest' image is still blurry when viewed with Evince.

Comment: Not sure, that would depend on the pdf-reader. Maybe asking a question on a site where apple-specific issues are handled?

Comment: If you use `pcolormesh` (and `ax.set_aspect(1)` if needed) I think the image will not be blurry.  You may want to rasterize the pcolor (`rasterized=True` in the list of kwargs).

Comment: Evince and Acrobat display the `interpolation='none'` fine, but Apple Preview does not. If possible I'd like it to work with Apple Preview and `imshow` somehow. Although maybe possible with `pcolormesh`, I'm not a fan of `pcolormesh's` N+1 pixel boundary coordinate convention and I already use a custom wrapper for `imshow` for my plots.